# return array with all matched elements based on user input

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need a help with a function that returns array with matched objects based on user input.

We enter value and search only inside this keys
1. title.label 
2. ['im:artist'].label

ES6 solution highly appriciated :-)

Thanks in advance.

```js
const fetchedData = [
{
"im:name": {
"label": "John Christmas songs"
},
"im:image": [
{
"label": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/a9/33/a5/a933a5a8-b731-c8aa-386d-4f6f78520cca/00602517645981.rgb.jpg/55x55bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "55"
}
},
{
"label": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/a9/33/a5/a933a5a8-b731-c8aa-386d-4f6f78520cca/00602517645981.rgb.jpg/60x60bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "60"
}
},
{
"label": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/a9/33/a5/a933a5a8-b731-c8aa-386d-4f6f78520cca/00602517645981.rgb.jpg/170x170bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "170"
}
}
],
"im:itemCount": {
"label": "25"
},
"im:price": {
"label": "$8.99",
"attributes": {
"amount": "8.99000",
"currency": "USD"
}
},
"im:contentType": {
"im:contentType": {
"attributes": {
"term": "Album",
"label": "Album"
}
},
"attributes": {
"term": "Music",
"label": "Music"
}
},
"rights": {
"label": "This Compilation ℗ 2008 EMI Music North America / Sony BMG Music / UMG Recordings, Inc."
},
"title": {
"label": "The Essential NOW That's What I Call Christmas - Various Artists"
},
"link": {
"attributes": {
"rel": "alternate",
"type": "text/html",
"href": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/the-essential-now-thats-what-i-call-christmas/1440793555?uo=2"
}
},
"id": {
"label": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/the-essential-now-thats-what-i-call-christmas/1440793555?uo=2",
"attributes": {
"im:id": "1440793555"
}
},
"im:artist": {
"label": "John Christmas"
},
"category": {
"attributes": {
"im:id": "8",
"term": "Holiday",
"scheme": "https://music.apple.com/us/genre/music-holiday/id8?uo=2",
"label": "Holiday"
}
},
"im:releaseDate": {
"label": "2008-01-01T00:00:00-07:00",
"attributes": {
"label": "January 1, 2008"
}
}
},
{
"im:name": {
"label": "The Essential NOW That's What I Call Christmas"
},
"im:image": [
{
"label": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/a9/33/a5/a933a5a8-b731-c8aa-386d-4f6f78520cca/00602517645981.rgb.jpg/55x55bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "55"
}
},
{
"label": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/a9/33/a5/a933a5a8-b731-c8aa-386d-4f6f78520cca/00602517645981.rgb.jpg/60x60bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "60"
}
},
{
"label": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/a9/33/a5/a933a5a8-b731-c8aa-386d-4f6f78520cca/00602517645981.rgb.jpg/170x170bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "170"
}
}
],
"im:itemCount": {
"label": "25"
},
"im:price": {
"label": "$8.99",
"attributes": {
"amount": "8.99000",
"currency": "USD"
}
},
"im:contentType": {
"im:contentType": {
"attributes": {
"term": "Album",
"label": "Album"
}
},
"attributes": {
"term": "Music",
"label": "Music"
}
},
"rights": {
"label": "This Compilation ℗ 2008 EMI Music North America / Sony BMG Music / UMG Recordings, Inc."
},
"title": {
"label": "The Essential NOW That's What I Call Christmas - Various Artists"
},
"link": {
"attributes": {
"rel": "alternate",
"type": "text/html",
"href": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/the-essential-now-thats-what-i-call-christmas/1440793555?uo=2"
}
},
"id": {
"label": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/the-essential-now-thats-what-i-call-christmas/1440793555?uo=2",
"attributes": {
"im:id": "1440793555"
}
},
"im:artist": {
"label": "Various Artists"
},
"category": {
"attributes": {
"im:id": "8",
"term": "Holiday",
"scheme": "https://music.apple.com/us/genre/music-holiday/id8?uo=2",
"label": "Holiday"
}
},
"im:releaseDate": {
"label": "2008-01-01T00:00:00-07:00",
"attributes": {
"label": "January 1, 2008"
}
}
},
{
"im:name": {
"label": "Christmas"
},
"im:image": [
{
"label": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/95/da/b2/95dab2db-b597-d466-490d-58aa56b54a17/093624942788.jpg/55x55bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "55"
}
},
{
"label": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/95/da/b2/95dab2db-b597-d466-490d-58aa56b54a17/093624942788.jpg/60x60bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "60"
}
},
{
"label": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/95/da/b2/95dab2db-b597-d466-490d-58aa56b54a17/093624942788.jpg/170x170bb.png",
"attributes": {
"height": "170"
}
}
],
"im:itemCount": {
"label": "16"
},
"im:price": {
"label": "$6.99",
"attributes": {
"amount": "6.99000",
"currency": "USD"
}
},
"im:contentType": {
"im:contentType": {
"attributes": {
"term": "Album",
"label": "Album"
}
},
"attributes": {
"term": "Music",
"label": "Music"
}
},
"rights": {
"label": "℗ 2011 Reprise Records"
},
"title": {
"label": "Christmas - Michael Bublé"
},
"link": {
"attributes": {
"rel": "alternate",
"type": "text/html",
"href": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/christmas/669854820?uo=2"
}
},
"id": {
"label": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/christmas/669854820?uo=2",
"attributes": {
"im:id": "669854820"
}
},
"im:artist": {
"label": "Michael Bublé",
"attributes": {
"href": "https://music.apple.com/us/artist/michael-bubl%C3%A9/799597?uo=2"
}
},
"category": {
"attributes": {
"im:id": "8",
"term": "Holiday",
"scheme": "https://music.apple.com/us/genre/music-holiday/id8?uo=2",
"label": "Holiday"
}
},
"im:releaseDate": {
"label": "2011-10-14T00:00:00-07:00",
"attributes": {
"label": "October 14, 2011"
}
}
}
]


Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );

var filtered = Object.filter(fetchedData, obj => obj['im:name'].label.includes('Christmas') || obj['im:artist'].label.includes('Christmas')  ); 
console.log(filtered);
```

Link to fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pr8vxyhn/2/

I achieved goal, sorry, I promise I`ll be more precise in future and always submit my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: Work on the logics and when you need debugging then only make a post in a Stack overflow.

Comment: please don't discourage new user, instead of that help them to understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this approach, here I'm using the arrow function. You have to make http request and fetch your data then apply this filter function.

```js
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );

// Example use:
var scores = {
    John: 2, Sarah: 3, Janet: 1
};
var filtered = Object.filter(scores, score => score > 1); 
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding and posting this solution. I used it on jsFiddle and achieved big part of a goal. Maybe you`ll take a look and help me find the aswer.

Comment: I voted but I must have more than 15 reputation points to let users see it

Comment: not that your question has been closed, next time try to elaborate your question